# A Go source appears in gray in Goland (IDEA). What does it mean? How do I make it return back to normal?

Tags: go, goland

Using Goland IDEA, a *Go* file is now grayed in one of my sources directories.

What does it mean? How do I make it return back to normal (black color)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the file color identification here:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/file-status-highlights.html#views

Gray means that the file is scheduled to be deleted from the repository.

[image: website description]

You can also check your Settings for the color set in your IDE.  Go to **Settings->Version Control->File Status Colors**.

[image: setting in IDE]

Comment: Thanks! But that's strange, because a `git status` from the console doesn't mark it for deletion, and the _Git_ windows inside _Golang_ doesn't mention anything about that `framing_test.go` file.

Comment: what happens if you do Git push or sync?  Is the file still there?

Comment: Also, check your VCS file status colors on the Version Control | File Status Colors page of the IDE settings to make sure that is what the color is set to on your system.
.

Comment: Could the file be in the ignored (.ignore plugin)?  That is what the color is set to in my IDE.  Go to Settings -> Version Control -> File Status Colors.

Comment: I'll check this in half a day (it's a problem at work, and I'm not there anymore, for today)

Answer (score 2):

Epilog:

I didn't made something special. The next morning my *Linux* session restarted and *Goland* was relaunched: the source file went normal again.

However, your answer is helpful, eglease, and I accept it.